How to update DF incrementally in Python
Description

I have a file which includes original data and updated statements.
The row original_id is like a primary key.
Rows which have no value in change_request_id are initial data entries.
Rows which have values in change_request_id are updates to the initial data entries.
The row change_request_id references the row original_id and represents a data change(update). Only values which need to be changed are represented as value, if the field is empty it means the value does not change.

Original File



change_request_id
original_id
a
b
c
d





1
10
20
30
40



2
2500
600
700
800


1
3
12





2
4

700
800



1
5

30





6
16
17
19
20



Desired Output:



change_request_id
original_id
a
b
c
d





1
12
30
30
40



2
500
700
800
800



6
16
17
19
20




You can replace original_id by change_request_id when not null (with fillna), then get the latest value per group with groupby.last:
out = (df.assign(original_id=df['change_request_id'].fillna(df['original_id']))
         .groupby('original_id', as_index=False).last()
         .drop(columns='change_request_id')
      )

Output:
   original_id      a      b      c       d
0          1.0    12.0   30.0   30.0   40.0
1          2.0  2500.0  700.0  800.0  800.0
2          6.0    16.0   17.0   19.0   20.0

